# 100V "rated" wire on 220V supply

Tags: voltage, current, safety, wire

I am genuinely sorry for posting such a basic, basic, *basic* question.

Moving to Thailand (220V) from Japan (100V). You cannot buy an extension cord in Thailand that is flush to the wall. Here in Japan, there are lots of angled extension cords from reputable companies that are flush. Most of these Japanese cords are rated at "1500W". If the only purpose is to connect a single 45W computer power adapter and nothing else, is it safe to use a "100V" Japanese extension cord without an intermediate step down transformer?

I have a basic understanding of electrical theory, which means I am fully qualified to burn my apartment building down to the ground. But I feel my neighbours would appreciate an informed opinion.

Comment: IMO, not a problem at all.

Comment: Depends what the voltage rating on the extension cord is. You may think you're qualified to burn your house down, your insurance company may think otherwise.

Comment: It might work without problems, but it is only rated for 100V so using it with 220V might be unsafe. That's all we can say. The power (Wattage) is irrelevant (for this question).

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Thank you for this. Most of the cables I've seen are rated in the 125V range and 15A, so I will just have to do without a flush cable. Finbarr, I am honestly, legitimately embarrassed at asking this question, so my closing sentence was just a self-deprecating jab at my own expense.

Comment: Have you inspected the cable? Does it have any marking on it, or numbers, logos? It could be very tinny, also not coloured but just a relief.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer if possible. It is quite possible that the 100V spec is just there to reassure people who use that voltage, and in fact the insulation can go to much higher voltages.

Comment: I have checked mine, it has a code H03VV-F. That means it is made to work up to 300VAC.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, I've not bought anything yet. Every extension cord we have now has some combination of switches, lamps and fuses, so there's no point in bringing them. However, all of the extension cord *wires* in our house are marked with the same Japanese safety agency mark: "<PS> E JET - F - KET" -- nothing about max voltage. The receptacles attached to the wire all specify 125V & 15A. But as I look now, I see most online manufacturer data sheets specify max 125V for nearly all consumer-level extension cords. I'd guess the actual upper limit is much higher, but the rated limit is 125V.

Comment: Would a Japanese cord even fit into a Thai outlet in the first place?  Usually the mechanics are different enough to prevent this.

Comment: @OlinLathrop -- Same hardware. Thailand's outlets come in a variety of standards, but our apartment accepts the same North American-type (ungrounded, flat, parallel, 2-prong plugs). The computer is a Mac with an unpolarized, ungrounded, power adapter. The same computers are sold in Thailand with the same power adapters (100-240V, 45W, 50-60Hz) -- clearly the surge danger is higher, but every Macbook you see there operates with the same risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**
The Japanese cable will work, but you may not want to use it.

Why?

As the 110v extension lead is designed to be plugged into 'mains', which experiences 1500v spikes whether on a 100v or 220v system, its insulation will be rated for at least those spikes. So 220v will be no problem.

However, after the fire (caused by some other random electrical thing overheating, or a cooking accident, or your 2 year old playing with matches) the insurance assessors will pick through the debris looking for reasons not to pay your claim. If they find a 100v rated extension lead plugged into a 220v system, even if it obviously didn't cause the fire, they might just make life difficult for you, just when you don't need it to be.

But check the rating. It's possible that extension leads available in Japan might be rated for 220v, even if Japan uses a 100v system, so that it's saleable in neighbouring territories. If it says 220v on it, then there's not even the insurance problem.

Comment: How would they know that is rated only for 100V?

Comment: @Marko Buršič Sometimes, you can see markings on the cable jacket or similar.

Comment: I've commented on one of @MarkoBuršič's comments with this, but the wires have a (inscrutable) safety agency marking on it and not much else. I can't be sure what the actual wire rating will be. And not to be down on Thailand or one of its neighbours, but most of the electrical goods you get there are manufactured in China. A few of the big-box stores guarantee their products, but I still feel it is a gamble. For me, this is risk analysis of Japanese over-engineering at 100V vs anonymous, discount engineering at 220V.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič - Since, apparently, flush (right angle connector) extension cords are not sold in Thailand, any inspection of an extension cord will instantly reveal its non-Thai origin. Further forensic effort might be applied, or the investigator might simply rule it inadequate.